# Using an if-else statement in big-query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to know how to implement this. I have written a SQL statement in big-query of this format:

```
with a( select * from tab1),
b as (select * from tab2),
select <field.a>,<field.b> from a inner join b on a.<field>=b.<field>
```

The above statement works a fine and returns me a number of records.
Now I want to introduce a **if** statement which checks for the presence of a value in the **logintab** table then only execute the above SQL statement.

So I do this:

```
if EXISTS (select * from logintab  WHERE
         emailid="xyz@org.com")
then
 with a( select * from tab1),
    b as (select * from tab2),
    select <field.a>,<field.b>,<...> from a join b on a.<field>=b.<field> order by endtime desc;
 end if;
```

but when I execute the above statement in bigquery console I'm just getting **true or false** as response instead of the results which I got without the if condition.

[image]

How to achieve the result such that I don't get **true** or **false** in the output whereas if it is true I get the records and if it's false I get an empty result-set?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve what you want to do.

```
with a as( select * from `dataset.tab1`),
b as(select * from `dataset.tab2`)
select a.field,b.field from a inner join b on a.id=b.id
where (select 1 from `dataset.logintab` where emailid="xyz@org.com")=1
```

The `If` expression only returns a true or a false according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if). That is why it only returns you false or true, and not the complete result.

The correct form to do this `IF` expression is to add an `ELSE` to correctly give you the answer.

Example:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from logintab  WHERE
         emailid="xyz@org.com")
then
 with a as( select * from `dataset.tab1`),
    b as(select * from `dataset.tab2`)
    select a.field,b.field from a inner join b on a.id=b.id
else
    select "NULL";
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `false` you're getting is likely the result of `exists(select * from logintab  WHERE emailid="xyz@org.com")`. If the result was `true`, the other query would have been executed, and you'd see its result as well.

You can check this by adding an `else` statement, e.g.

```
if EXISTS (select * from logintab  WHERE
         emailid="xyz@org.com")
then
 with a( select * from tab1),
    b as (select * from tab2),
    select <field.a>,<field.b>,<...> from a join b on a.<field>=b.<field> order by endtime desc;
else
    select "No logintab found";
end if;
```

EDIT:
When you use a query for the predicate, BigQuery will run it in a separate job, i.e. there will be one job with the result you're seeing (true/false) and another job with the result you want. Both should be visible in the Cloud Console.

If you use `bq` (or the API), you should get the result you want, e.g.

```
❯ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'if exists(select 1) then select "then branch"; else select "else branch"; end if;'
Waiting on bqjob_r35c4f0d7545198ab_0000017f5f13a4d4_1 ... (1s) Current status: DONE
select "then branch"; -- at [1:26]
+-------------+
|     f0_     |
+-------------+
| then branch |
+-------------+
```

Comment: yes i dont want false or true in the result instead if it is false the resultset should be empty but if it is true i want the records returned

Comment: Also if it is true, as i have updated above i dont get the result instead i just get true